# HTTP GET: Best Practice for complex parameters

Tags: http, rest

As far as I know, HTTP Get shouldn't have request body but can have some parameters like `https://url/path?parameter=someparameter`

However, if I want to GET some data with complex parameter (array with many elements), is it okay to use PUT or POST to **get** data with request body? Or it is better to just send request body to GET path?

The scenario is I have a question database and want users to be able to random for a question and filter for difficulty level, average time used, number of answers, and multiple questions they want to exclude.